# number_format and sprintf for same variable

Tags: php

How can I have two leading zeros and two decimal places for the same number. I tried the code below but only number_format or sprintf seems to work (they don't seem to work together)

```
sprintf("%04d", number_format((float)$height, 2, '.', ''))
```

The above code returns 0025 instead of 0025.00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%d` is for integers. Use `%f` for float:

```
%0        7        .2       f
 padding  TOTAL    decimal  float
 char     string   digits   type
          length
```

In your case:

```
sprintf( '%07.2f', (float) $height );
```

Output:

```
0025.00
```